# Bcrypt password generated online does not validate with `bcrypt`

Tags: bcrypt

I'm using the `bcrypt` npm package, and this site https://bcrypt.online/

If I do this, it works as expected

```
> await bcrypt.compare("foo", await bcrypt.hash("foo", 10));
true
```

Now if I go to and generate the a hash for `foo`, when I try to verify it, it always return false

```
> await bcrypt.compare("foo", "$2y$10$/8SXjDtJiFtwWg6Jvz./3e7AVgPY2.BKzfwU4Y29OetJLz6W6Biuu");
false
```

I cannot understand why this is happening